# DuplicateEmailErrorMessage in Asp.Net membership CreateUser control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

I would like to know if there is a way to show my CreateUserControl.DuplicateEmailErrorMessage  text in the validation summary that I have on my page.

I was able to find CreateUserControl.ErrorMessageStyle to add styles to my error message but I would rather show it in the validation summary control that I already have on my page.

Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Note: I know I can come up with my own validation for the duplicated emails and show them using a new validator in my validation Summary control but I was just wondering if it is possible to perform the above.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2011/04/13/Displaying-CreateUserWizard_1920_s-Provider-Errors-in-a-ValidationSummary.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) helped me resolve this issue.

This can be resolved by handling the CreateUserError(object sender, CreateUserErrorEventArgs e) event